# Delete Structs with Duplicate Field Values from a Slice of Structs

Tags: loops, go, struct, duplicates

I have a slice of structs and each struct has two fields. I want to delete a struct from the slice if there is a duplicate value only in the first field. I've tried using loops within loops, maps, and sorting but I can't figure it out.

The closest I've come is deleting a struct from the slice if both fields have the same value as another struct but I need to delete it if the first field has the same value as another struct in the slice.

There are many examples online of doing these when all fields in the struct have the same value but I haven't found any for the case I'm discribing.

The actual program I'm working on is much more complex and it requires that I use a slice of structs.

I've made a simplified example below which gets to the heart of the problem.

It outputs `[{one 1} {one 2} {five 5}]` The desired output is `[{one 1} {five 5}]`

Thank you in advance for the help.

```
import "fmt"

type myKey struct {
    key string
    num int
}

type myKeysList []myKey

func remDupKeys(m myKeysList) myKeysList {
    keys := make(map[myKey]bool)
    list := myKeysList{}
    for _, entry := range m {
        if _, value := keys[entry]; !value {
            keys[entry] = true
            list = append(list, entry)
        }
    }
    return list
}
func main() {

    one := myKey{"one", 1}
    two := myKey{"one", 1}
    three := myKey{"one", 2}
    four := myKey{"one", 1}
    five := myKey{"five", 5}

    myKeysList := myKeysList{one, two, three, four, five}
    fmt.Println(myKeysList)
    uList := remDupKeys(myKeysList)
    fmt.Println(uList)
}
```

Go Playground Link https://play.golang.org/p/x8sNjW_mxrl

Comment: Is there a reason that `{one 1} {one 2}` becomes `{one 1}`? Or can it becomes `{one 2}`? In other words, how would you discard structs with one different field?

Comment: On the other hand, you can just use a `map[string]myKey` and use `entry.key` as the key of the map.

Comment: In the actual program, the second field is a timestamp which is converted to an int64 and sorted with the oldest occurrence first. It would be fine to just keep the first occurrence of a struct with the key "one" and disregard all others.  The acutal output looks like this ``dupList: [{BK048523/1 dragonfly 1605385863} {BK048523/1 dragonfly 1605385712} {BK033116/1 dragonflykings 1605383905} {BK033116/1 dragonflykings 1605383453} {BK033116/1 dragonflykings 1605383365} {BK048531/1 dragonfly 1605381867} {BK048531/1 dragonfly 1605381795}]``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea in the question is correct: record visited values in a map and skip values already in the map.

To remove duplicates based a single field in a struct, use the field as the map key:

```
func remDupKeys(m myKeysList) myKeysList {
    keys := make(map[string]bool)
    list := myKeysList{}
    for _, entry := range m {
        if _, ok := keys[entry.key]; !ok {
            keys[entry.key] = true
            list = append(list, entry)
        }
    }
    return list
}
```

Comment: Very simple solution and it works beautifully. I thought there was something basic I was missing. I was stuck thinking the map needed to be of the same type as the struct ``map[myKey]bool``